# Pattern to lookup a slice element by an injected type

Tags: go, interface, type-assertion

I've attempted to lookup objects inside a interface slice using the type of the object. This current solution I have looks as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type Entity struct {
    children []Childable
}

func (e *Entity) ChildByInterface(l interface{}) (Childable, error) {
    for _, c := range e.children {
        if fmt.Sprintf("%T", c) == fmt.Sprintf("%T", l) {
            return c, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, errors.New("child doesn't exist")
}

type Childable interface {
    GetName() string
}

func main() {
    ent := &Entity{
        []Childable{
            &Apple{name: "Appy"},
            &Orange{name: "Orry"},
            // more types can by introduced based on build tags
        },
    }

    appy, err := ent.ChildByInterface(&Apple{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        appy.(*Apple).IsRed()
        fmt.Printf("%+v", appy)
    }
}

type Apple struct {
    name string
    red  bool
}

func (a *Apple) GetName() string {
    return a.name
}

func (a *Apple) IsRed() {
    a.red = true
}

type Orange struct {
    name   string
    yellow bool
}

func (o *Orange) GetName() string {
    return o.name
}

func (o *Orange) IsYellow() {
    o.yellow = true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FmkWILBqqA-

More Childable types (Apple, Orange, ...) can be injected using build tags. So in order to keep the lookup type safe and avoid mistakes, I'm passing an `interface{}` to the lookup function. The Childable interface also assures the newly injected types implement the correct functions.

This is where things start to get messy. Currently I'm doing a string comparison on both the interface's type and the Childable object's type to see if they match:
`fmt.Sprintf("%T", c) == fmt.Sprintf("%T", l)`

Then I can still only return the Childable interface. So I have to use type assertion to get the correct type: `appy.(*Apple)`

The boiler plating is to get the child in its correct type has become very tedious and the string comparison to find a match is having a significant performance impact. What better solution can I use to match two interfaces with each other to avoid the performance knock?

Comment: Interfaces are used that way it is required to type assert the value to get underlying type. What is that you want to achieve ?

Comment: Apply explicit type assertion on the returned value is the way to do it. You will always have "performance" impact as you rely on runtime information to execute the implementation. This might be close to what you are looking for the type equality test https://github.com/mh-cbon/service-finder/blob/master/service-finder.go#L38

Comment: isn't it better with something like `Is("red")` and call `Is` function on both objects ?

Comment: @danicheeta I just added the IsRed and IsYellow functions to show that the two structs should be able to have different methods (therefore require type assertion). Based on what you are suggesting, I realize how inefficient they are.

Answer (score 1):

As far `fmt.Sprintf("%T", c)` used `reflect` under the hood there are no advantages to imply it - better use `reflect` directly.
You can use reference argument as a placeholder of a result instead of return value.

```
func (e *Entity) ChildByInterface(l Childable) error {
    for _, c := range e.children {
        if reflect.TypeOf(l) == reflect.TypeOf(c) {
            fmt.Println(c)
            reflect.ValueOf(l).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(c).Elem())
            return nil
        }
    }
    return errors.New("child doesn't exist")
}
```

Now pass a placeholder

```
apple := &Apple{}
err := ent.ChildByInterface(apple)
//and use it
apple.IsRed()
```

[Working code](https://play.golang.org/p/P2PZtxxw9jV)

Comment: @Himanshu the interface is there to allow additional structs to be introduced via new build tags and still assure it "implements" the Childable interface.

Comment: @FanusduToit good for bringing that up. Please edit your question and add this requirement it will be helpful.

Comment: @Uvelichitel Wouldn't the following line you are using result in essentially cloning the value instead of returning the pointer to the original value? `reflect.ValueOf(l).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(c).Elem())`

Comment: It fill the address which `l` point to with value dereferenced from `c`

Comment: Yes, so if I'm understanding you correctly, the memory address of this `apple := &Apple{}` will not be the same address as this `&Apple{name: "Appy"}` since the former will allocate additional memory just for the sake of this slice lookup. Isn't that a bit excessive?

Comment: If I correctly understand your question you want to use a value you are looking up. Sure you must allocate space for this value.

Comment: If you don't want to allocate and copy value from slice you can just return slice[index]. Code will be far more simple.